# 2 different blocks of text are merging together. Can I separate them if i know what 1 is?

Tags: python, regex, pdf, extract

I've used a number of pdf-->text methods to extract text from pdf documents.  For one particular type of PDF I have, neither pyPDF or pdfMiner are doing a good job extracting the text.  However, http://www.convertpdftotext.net/ does it (almost) perfectly.

I discovered that the pdf I'm using has some transparent text in it, and it is getting merged into the other text.

Some examples of the blocks of text I get back are:

```
12324  35th Ed. 01-MAR-12 Last LNM: 14/12 NAD 83 14/12          Corrective             Object of Corrective                                                                                                                   
ChartTitle: Intracoastal Waterway Sandy Hook to Little Egg Harbor Position  
            C HAActRionT    N  Y  -NJ   - S A  N  D Y    H OO    K  ATcO tionLI T TLE EGG HARBOR.  Page/Side: N/A 
(Temp) indicates that the chart correction action is temporary in nature.  Courses and bearings are givCGenD 0in 1 degrees clockwise from 000 true.       
 Bearings RoEf LlighOCtAT seEc tors aSrehre towwsbuardry th Re ivligher Ct fhroanmn seel Lawighartde.d  B Theuoy  5no minal range of lights is expressedf roin mna 4u0tic-24al -mi46les.56 0(NNM ) unless othe0r7w4is-00e n-o05te.d8.8 0 W 
to     40-24-48.585N 074-00-05.967W
```

and

```
12352 33rd Ed. 01-MAR-11 Last LNM: 03/12 NAD 83 04/12 . . l . . . . Corrective Object of Corrective ChartTitle: Shinnecock Bay to East Rockaway Inlet Position C HAActRionT S H IN N E C OC K B A Y TO AcEtionAS T ROCKAWAY INLET. Page/Side: N/A (Temp) indicates that the chart correction action is temporary in nature. Courses and bearings are givCGenD 0in 1 degrees clockwise from 000 true. (BTeeamringp) s DoEf LlighETtE s ectors aSretat toew Baoratd Ctheh anlighnet lf Droaym beseacoawanr 3d. The nominal range of lights is expressedf roin mna 4u0tic-37al -mi11les.52 0(NNM ) unless othe0r7w3is-29e n-5o3te.d76. 0 W
```

and I have discovered that the "ghost text" is **ALWAYS** the following:

```
 Corrective             Object of Corrective              Position
    Action                         Action
```

(Temp) indicates that the chart correction action is temporary in nature.  Courses and bearings are given in degrees clockwise from 000 true.
Bearings of light sectors are toward the light from seaward.  The nominal range of lights is expressed in nautical miles (NM) unless otherwise noted.

In the 2nd example I posted, the text I want (with the ghost text removed) is:

```
12352 33rd Ed. 01-Mar-11 Last LNM:03/12 NAD 83 04/12
Chart Title:Shinnecock Bay to East Rockaway Inlet. Page/Side:N/A 
CGD01
(Temp) DELETE State Boat Channel Daybeacon 3 from 40-37-11.520N 073-29-53.760W
```

This problem occurs just once per document, and does not appear to be totally consistent (as seen above).  I am wondering if one of you wizards could think of a way to remove the ghosted text (I don't need/want it) using python.  If I had been using pyPDF, I would have used a regex to rip it out during the conversion to text.  Unfortunately, since I'm starting out with a text file from the website listed above, the damage has already been done.  I'm at a bit of a loss.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:
The solution to this problem looks like it be more complex than the rest of the application, so I'm going to withdraw my request for help.

I very much appreciate the thought put into it by those who have contributed.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the ghost text can be split up in seemingly unpredictable ways, I don't think there is a simple automatic way of removing it that would not have false positives. What you need is almost human-level pattern recognition. :-)

What you could try is exploiting the format of these kinds of messages. Roughly;

```
<number> <number>[rn]d Ed. <date> Last LNM:<mm>/<yy> NAD <date2>
Chart Title:<text>. Page/Side:<N/A or number(s)> CGD<number> <text>
<position>
```

Using this you could pluck out the nonsense from the predictable elements, and then if you have a list of chart names ('Shinnecock Bay to East Rockaway Inlet') and descriptive words (like 'State', 'Boat', 'Daybeacon') you might be able to reconstruct the original words by finding the smallest levenshtein distance between mangled words in the two text blocks and those in your word lists.

If you can install the [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) software, you could try and use `pdftotext` with the `-layout` option to keep the formatting from the original PDF as much as possible. That might make your problem disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You could recursively find all possible ways that your Pattern 
"Corrective Object of Corrective Position Action ..." can be contained within your mangled text,

Then you can unmangle the text for each of these possible paths, run some sort of spellcheck over them, and choose the one with the fewest spelling mistakes. Or since you know roughly where each substring should appear, you can use that as a heuristic.
Or you could simply use the first path.

some pseudocode (untested):

```
 def findPaths(mangledText, pattern, path)
      if len(pattern)==0:  # end of pattern
           return [path]
      else:
           nextLetter= pattern[0]
           locations = findAllOccurences (mangledText, nextLetter) # get all indices in mangledText that contain nextLetter
           allPaths = []
           for loc in locations:
               paths = findPaths( mangledText[loc+1:], pattern[1:], path + (loc,) )
               allPaths.Extend(paths)
           return allPaths # if no locations for the next letters exist, allPaths will be emtpy
```

Then you can call it like this (optionally remove all spaces from your search pattern, unless you are certain they are all included in the mangled text)

```
  allPossiblePaths = findPaths ( YourMangledText, "Corrective Object...", () )
```

then allPossiblePaths should contain a list of all possible ways your pattern could be contained in your mangled text.
Each entry is a tuple with the same length as the pattern, containing the index at which the corresponding letter of the pattern occurs in the search text.